# simplest solution to write a java web app run on tomcat: just list a few db records by id

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

When asking this I answered myself: use a jsp.

But ok, what about a lightweight, easy to use framework?

It would be perfect if this framework had Eclipse plugin, 
so that I could generate all code in one click and **simply fill one method body**  (populate it with the data), then in one click 
create a war file using a wizard
and deploy it on Tomcat.

Are there such frameworks?

p.s. I use spring, but I think there are ways to integrate it into every framework.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo).

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to list a few DB records, I would just implement it dirty with a simple JSP with scriptlets. But you could also use the [JSP SQL Tag library](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html) for that.

A simple one method body controller that needs that forwards to a view can most easily be writen with the [Stripes framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/) that forwards to a JSP view (see [wikipedia code example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripes_(framework)) for how easy this can be done).

Generating nice tables in JSP can quickly be done by the popular [Display Tag library](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If your not afraid to learn something new take a look at [Grails](http://grails.org/)

One of the big advantages of Grails is that its a full stack environment. Meaning that out of the box you get everything you need for your web app development

- Test Servlet container (Tomcat)
- Test database (hypersonic)
- ORM (hibernate)

  etc.....

Once installed just run

```
> grails create-app
```

Then you have a complete runnable application. (Auto bootstraps your project creation and config)